# Aligning Dynamically generated user control in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one panel and one user control,
you can generate a user control as many as u want by clicking the button. But it only generates one line per user control then proceed to next line, i want to make, 3 user control per line then proceed to next line (looping).
The size of My panel Container is (1019, 516)
and my user control is (322, 129)

and this is my code :

```
    int poss = 10;        
    public void AddItems(string Text, bool Checked, Image imagee, string prices)
    {
        DynaItems item = new DynamicUserControl.DynaItems(Text, Checked, imagee, prices);
        PanelContainer.Controls.Add(item);
        item.Top = poss;
        poss = (item.Top + item.Height + 10);
    }
```

is it possible to achieve this? 
Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dfU9.jpg 
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: You set only Top. You should set also Left or just set Location to control both dimensions.

Comment: Usage of the TableLayoutPanel might make this job much easier here.

Comment: A FlowLayoutPanel would be an even better choice as it would do the wrapping for you...